# Write some data (lines) from my mappers to separate directories depending on some logic in my mapper code

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce, mrjob

I am using mrjob for my EMR needs.

How do I write some data (lines) from my mappers to "separate directories" depending on some logic in my mapper code that I can:

1. tar gzip and
2. upload to separate S3 buckets (depending on the directory name) after the job finishes/terminates abruptly?

I guess the '`--output-dir`' options only allows you to upload the final job output to that directory, but I would like to write to other directories as well from time to time from my mappers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you can't in the traditional sense.**

Reason:  MrJob internally uses Hadoop streaming to run map/reduce jobs when running with Hadoop cluster I am assuming that this is same for Amazon Elastic M/R as it is for Hadoop cluster.

The `--output-dir` is actually an input to Hadoop streaming which specifies where the the output of reducers will be collected. You can not use this mechanism for segregating data into different folders.

[Edit: In response to comment]

My understanding is that boto is only a library to connect to Amazon services and access ec2 and s3 etc.

**In a non-traditional sense you can still write to different directories, I guess.**

I have not tested this idea and don't recommend this approach. This would be like opening a file and writing to it directly within the reducers. Theoretically you could do that.  Instead of just writing the reducer output to std.out. You could possibly open and write to S3 objects directly. You have to ensure that you will open different files as it spawns multiple reducers.

This is what I learned while using MrJob with Hadoop cluster: http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2012/05/hadoop-map-reduce-with-mrjob.html

Comment: Thinking deeper: MrJob ships with a certain version of boto. Now could I employ that to write to a local folder, or failing that, to a "remote" S3 bucket?

Comment: I am still looking for a way to reduce the number of PUTs to S3 (right now I'm firing off at least one PUT for every line other I get)

Comment: Also, where does the data written to STDERR end up for MrJob? (I am assuming all STDOUT output goes to the location pointed to by '--output-dir')

Comment: @newToFlume: Both log files. See http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.17.0/mapred_tutorial.html#Debugging

Comment: That link does not seem useful for Hadoop Streaming, but thanks Ashish for the followup.

Answer (score 1):

I think Hadoop's `MultipleOutput` feature can help you, in your custom `outputFormat` you can specify the path and filename.

Comment: I think you may not do this in Hadoop Streaming currently, http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/streaming.html#How+do+I+provide+my+own+input%2Foutput+format+with+streaming%3F, it says you have to use custom jar. But I may be wrong

Comment: You can certainly have a custom jar run as a Hadoop streaming job. An example command shall look like :
ruby elastic-mapreduce –jobflow <jobFlow ID> --jar <s3-jar-file-path> --arg <s3-input-folder-path> --arg <s3-output-folder-path>  --step-name "My Streaming Job Step"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach of creating custom Jar and customize your `OutputFormat` in order to mutiplex outputs in different folders/files. You shall create a subclass of `MultipleTextOutputFormat` and override few of the methods in it (`generateFileNameForKeyValue(Text key, Text value, String leaf)` and `generateActualKey(Text key, Text value)` mainly).

For more details you can refer this : http://www.infoq.com/articles/HadoopOutputFormat